# windowtester click all buttons with the same name

Tags: swing, findall, window-tester

I'm using window tester and I have a wizard with three buttons with the same text: "Select all".
If there is only one button, I do
    ui.click(new JButtonLocator("Select all"));

with three, I was trying to use
    IWidgetLocator[] allSelectAll = ui.findAll(new JButtonLocator("Select all"));
and then use the IWidgetLocator to click one or all of them. How can I do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following constructor for this:

`JButtonLocator(String label, int index, SwingWidgetLocator parent)`

Specify the index (zero-based) and the parent widget (eg. JFrame):

`ui.click(new JButtonLocator("Select all", 0, new SwingWidgetLocator(JFrame.class)));`

This should let you click on the first of the "Select all" buttons. Just change the index to do the same for the other buttons.

HTH